# Как распарсить выгрузку из MySQL - расширение файла-выгрузки .enr?

Tags: mysql

Есть стороннее ПО в нём всё платно и всё криво работает, но есть выгрузка.
Есть собственное разработанное ПО быстрое, корректное, выигрывшее конкуренцию по работе, но без выгрузки (есть обмен по FTP, но это другая, внутренняя выгрузка).
Организация требует выгрузку в своём формате .enr, но параметры для выгрузки не предоставляет, но требует приобретения пролоббированного ПО.
Вопрос - как можно распарсить .enr из MySQL?

Comment: Расширение файла не говорит ни о чём. Всё зависит от внутреннего формата содержащихся в нём данных. А поскольку MySQL умеет выгружать только в текстовые файлы, структура должна быть прозрачной (параноики, сливающие данные в шифрованные хексы - редкость).

Comment: @Akina, но допустим я для оптимизации передачи данных не шифрую, а архивирую файл компонентом Delphi, расширение задаю какой угодно. Естественно если смотреть с наскоку, то будет лишь неструктурированный массив данных - эдакий RAW-массив.
Вот именно по этому и пытался по первым байтам HEX-кода, узнать что и к чему. Но поиски не привели к результатам.

Comment: *пытался по первым байтам HEX-кода, узнать что и к чему* А нам показать постеснялся? хотя бы первые 256 байт скриншотом... А заодно указать фамилию этого "пролоббированного ПО".

Comment: @ ПО "АИПС-УНЦБ безопасное пользование оружием".
Первые 512 байт HEX-кода заголовка:
https://krasnovosti.ru/temp/listing.txt

Comment: Мне опознать формат не удалось. Увы...

Comment: @Akina, благодарен за, хотя бы, внимание к вопросу. Про опознать формат, сам знаю, не первый месяц с этой проблемой вожусь. У кого хорошие связи с МВД, те эту проблему решили... Я же с МВД дружб не вожу.
Ещё раз спасибо.